# How use markercluster with data already clustered?

Tags: leaflet.markercluster

I truly like the design of markercluster, that's why I would like to use it for my application, but all my data are already clustered, I can get them under any format (tree, dict of lists, etc).

I tried to reuse the markercluster class with fake markerclustergroup, like this

That a small example of what I tried to do:

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
    zoom: 0,
    center: [0,0],
    minZoom: -6,
    maxZoom: 30,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
});
// {0: {1: {3: {}}, {4: {}}}, {2: {5: {}}, {6: {}}}}
var root = 0;
const dNode = {
    3: [[], [-2, -1], 2],
    4: [[], [-1, -2], 2],
    5: [[], [2, 1], 2],
    6: [[], [1, 2], 2],
    1: [[3,4], [-1, -1], 1],
    2: [[5,6], [1,1], 1],
    0: [[1, 2], [0,0], 0],
};
map.fitBounds([[-2, -2], [2, 2]]);

for (var node of [3,4,5,6,1,2,0]) {
    var info = dNode[node];
    var children = info[0];
    if (children.length!=0) {
        var a = Object.create(Object);
        a._featureGroup = new L.featureGroup();
        for (child of children) {
            dNode[child][3].addTo(a._featureGroup);
        }
        a.options = {
            clusterPane: L.Marker.prototype.options.pane,
            iconCreateFunction: function (h) {
                return new L.divIcon({html: "AhA", iconSize: "auto"});
            }
        };
        a._map = map;
        var markers = new L.MarkerCluster(a, info[2], L.LatLng(...info[1]));
        info[3] = markers;
    } else {
        info[3] = new L.marker(info[1]);
    }
}
dNode[root][3].addTo(map);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Layers Control Tutorial - Leaflet</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it didn't seem to work, because when I click on the 'AhA' cluster, nothing happened...

May you know how I can do it ? (I'm not too good at javascript ^^')